# how to check package version before install

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, apache2.4

Im trying to install Apache 2.4.12 or apache2.4 at least.
I see some listings for apache2.2 in the apt-cache, but I don't see apache2.4.
How can I verify the actually version that `sudo  apt-get install apache2`
will install, without having to install?

Answer (score 9):

do:

```
apt-cache policy apache2
```

you'll get output like this:

```
apache2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1
  Version table:
     2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.4.7-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

The version listed as "Candidate" is the one that will be installed if you do `apt-get install apache2`.

If there's more than one version available, you can force which one you want by giving the version number, in my example it would by default install 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1 but I can force the other version with:

```
apt-get install apache2=2.4.7-1ubuntu4
```